# NextJS send data on redirect inside getServerSideProps

Tags: redirect, next.js, server-side-rendering

Is there a posibility to send data with redirect inside getServerSideProps function similar way as in next.config.js (you cannot pass hidden queries as far as I know inside next config file).

```
export const getServerSideProps = async (context) => {
    const id = context.params.id;
    
    return {
        redirect: {
            destination: '/my-work',
            permanent: false,
            has: [
                {
                    type: 'query',
                    value: id
                }
            ]
        },
        props: {
                
        }
    }
}
```

I want to pass hidden query to another page so this only works as middleware redirection as I am comming on this page from email template. But has object is not working in getServerSideProps function.

Is there any other ways to achieve that?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do the check yourself, e.g. `if (context.params.id) { return { redirect: { ... } }; }`.

Answer (score 0):

This is from the official documentation.

```
module.exports = {
  async redirects() {
    return [
      // if the header `x-redirect-me` is present,
      // this redirect will be applied
      {
        source: '/:path((?!another-page$).*)',
        has: [
          {
            type: 'header',
            key: 'x-redirect-me',
          },
        ],
        permanent: false,
        destination: '/another-page',
      },
      // if the source, query, and cookie are matched,
      // this redirect will be applied
      {
        source: '/specific/:path*',
        has: [
          {
            type: 'query',
        key: 'page',
        // the page value will not be available in the
        // destination since value is provided and doesn't
        // use a named capture group e.g. (?<page>home)
        value: 'home',
      },
      {
        type: 'cookie',
        key: 'authorized',
        value: 'true',
      },
    ],
    permanent: false,
    destination: '/another/:path*',
  },
  // if the header `x-authorized` is present and
  // contains a matching value, this redirect will be applied
  {
    source: '/',
    has: [
      {
        type: 'header',
        key: 'x-authorized',
        value: '(?<authorized>yes|true)',
      },
    ],
    permanent: false,
    destination: '/home?authorized=:authorized',
  },
  // if the host is `example.com`,
  // this redirect will be applied
  {
    source: '/:path((?!another-page$).*)',
    has: [
      {
        type: 'host',
        value: 'example.com',
      },
    ],
    permanent: false,
    destination: '/another-page',
  },
]
```

},
}

You can compare the params with it. For more details, visit [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/redirects)